# Make last argument conditionally optional typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to make last arg of function conditionally optional, eg. if previous argument has type null, make last optionial (`?`), if previous has value, make last arg required.

Is this possible?

Playground here:
https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMGBeGAeAKgRgDQxYBMAfABQAOAhgE5UC2OAXIfjNXfUS7jAKYAPKHzAATCDDAIANtJgB+SXwBufGjxwBKNCRgBvAL4BuAFAmA9OZgALNXxg0+ARwQBLRzFoBzE4mRkAcilZAM1TCytbRwIwEFhHF3d7Yl8kYDJg6TCTIA

Comment: Sounds more like you need to supply an options object. You can define two shapes of it and declare `fn(options: TwoParamObject | SingleParamObject)` where the `SingleParamObject` doesn't allow `null` for the first property.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a union of [rest tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions) to give you this behavior:

```
const func = (...param: [null, unknown?] | [unknown, unknown]) => {};

func("a", "b"); // okay
func("a"); // error!  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'null'.
func(null); // okay
func(null, "b"); // okay
```

Or, you could use the traditional (pre-TS3.0) solution to this, [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads):

```
const func: {
  (param1: null, param2?: unknown): void; // first call signature
  (param1: unknown, param2: unknown): void; // second call signature
} = (param1: unknown, param2?: unknown) => {};

func("a", "b"); // okay
func("a"); // error!  Type '"a"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'null'.
func(null); // okay
func(null, "b"); // okay
```

Either of those should work for you.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAlaAXAKgVxgG2iQG8BYAKCSXgHtgp0kAzbYeJAXiQAoA6PuAE7gAXEgDawbHjwAaJCwDWwagHdgAfgC6SAD7jFytXIOrgmgJQcAfMQC+AbnLlKzVlwBEId3PcAjd+b2SAD0wUjUCiAAns5MLPAeXoEhYRACAtQCAISUmFEwyADk9AIAlsAA5oVIpVBIygwgUFClFaC+BEjo1F35RZLShTyxrgkDeMmh4ZExFHFu4z7+k2ER0eS2TmSgkLAIyADyAG5peNQgACZ1pHM0dAyjojeUlFyC4ACMootI72AATOpRCY1OZREdqKULo45q8-l95MAlKY5H9-sCkYZgGCkBCoTDKLYONx4RjkUZfiAhACgYjydjrHYYSN4olvEg-AEglM1rMXKzPFyUkg0hlsrk+khCoLqrV6tRGs1Wu1Ot1KdSIOg0uFGL0ClLxkMWQspBNuasZsaxqalkKeZayJsyFsgA)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is better expressed as two mutually exclusive parameter objects. You can define two (or more) types that your function expects.

- One will only have a single value and that value would be `null`. For ease, I will also make the value optional:

```js
interface SingleParamObject {
    param1?: null
}
```

- The next type has two parameters and mandates that the first one is not `null`:

```js
interface TwoParamObject<T1, T2> {
    param1: NonNullable<T1>,
    param2: T2
}
```

This is a bit more typing for *this* case, at least but I think it addresses the problem more comprehensively - you either want to pass a parameter object with `param1` either missing or `null` or you want both `param1` and `param2`:

```js
const func = <T1, T2>(params: SingleParamObject|TwoParamObject<T1, T2>) => {};
```

This makes it more expressive what you want to do and you can also add more shapes for parameter objects - perhaps you want nothing, or `param1` + `param2`, or `param1` + `param2` + `param3` + `param4`, or whatever combinations you want.

[Check on TypeScript Playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMqgOYBsIAU5RwC2A8gEYBWECYyA3gFDLPIAOBxAjAPwBcyIAK5YsDAL4MGoSLEQoAKgHcA9vkKlK1MAB55nADTJ5AJgB89Ji3brO-AHLKQd4Vjhkcuzqf2Xm14sb8JuKSCI4AzrQwgiAIyAC8yJ6GJqYAFP5E4fzoINh4HBpUNAA+SqqF5MU6eilmAJQJ5nRiANySAPQdyAAW0ChQEACOgsCDyAQYDNGxaYwsbIW2yABEfSLKK+L17dMxCHO+izb8axAbKz4LmYGrKlBYACZbYjud3X2DhiDKtIMjYwUxj2s3mViW-CEIm27RmBzBfghAhcV3B6luZw2yHuTxebxB8Ne7SAA)